# Does anyone know where I can find the PHP APC DLL for PHP 5.3.5?

Tags: php, apc

I tried looking on http://downloads.php.net/pierre, but I couldn't find a binary for APC on PHP 5.3.5. Does anyone know where I could find it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the APC documentation on php.net (http://php.net/manual/apc.installation.php):

> A DLL for this PECL extension is currently unavailable. See also the [building on Windows](http://php.net/manual/install.windows.building.php) section.

Probably not the answer you were hoping for, but hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

Answer (score 0):

You can download it here: http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-accelerators/apc.html